# PackageKit-command-not-found: Failed to install packages: Failed to obtain authentication

Tags: linux, fedora, installation-package

I'm currently running Fedora 37 Server edition, after I installed `PackageKit-command-not-found`, it **should** install package when command does not exists, but it just say `Failed to install packages: Failed to obtain authentication.`

Console:

```
$> cowsay
bash: cowsay: command not found...
Install package 'cowsay' to provide command 'cowsay'? [N/y] y
 * Waiting in queue...
The following packages have to be installed:
 cowsay-3.7.0-6.fc37.noarch     Configurable speaking/thinking cow
Proceed with changes? [N/y] y
 * Waiting in queue...
 * Waiting for authentication... Failed to install packages: Failed to obtain authentication.
```

Comment: * Waiting for authentication...  It is supposed at some point before or after this message you provide the root password, once a given amount of time has passed and there is nothing written it exits just like these.

Comment: No, it just skipped and didn't ask for root password

Comment: I've tried to change root password but no success.

Comment: You don't have to change the root password, just provide at the moment you install something. I'm not used to fedora so I'm not pretty sure what is the "PackageKit-command-not-found", guessing it must need some extra configuration.

Comment: But it didn't ask for password

Comment: I don't use fedora, so I'm unable to tell if this is the normal operation.